# CSS - margin-left, top alternatives

Tags: css, html, dom

To position any element on the DOM, i use margin-left, margin-top : px most of the time.
Are there any alternatives and is it a good practice to use the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually for positioning an element inside the DOM the `position:relative;` and / or `position:absolute;` are used.

Setting `position:absolute;` in an element you set its position in the document with the top, right, bottom an left properties.

If you want to set its position to another element, you set the parent element to `position:relative;`, which I assume is your usual scenario

For example, an alternative to `margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;` would be:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>  
<style>
#outer { position:relative; }
#inner { position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; }
</style>
```

Using these properties can be a bit tricky, but it gives you more flexibility. You can read more about it [here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).